# How to randomly generate an Integer in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, random

As the question suggests.

I need to randomly generate an Integer at the end of my SQL query. It is supposed to be part of a code that I have to create from existing variables.

```
SELECT LEFT(Var1,2) & RIGHT(Var2,1) & RND
FROM MyTable;
```

The method I used here generates a number that is a decimal like 0,2895625 at the end of the code. I need it to generate a whole Integer.

Thanks Again!

Comment: if my below solution is helpful for you then accept it as an answer buddy.

Comment: It is helpful. Dont get me wrong. But it is not what I am looking for unfortunately.

Comment: what you are looking for? can you explain with example. I have updated my answer also.

Comment: It has to use that Rnd() function. But it cannot use data types like TinyInt. My rubric says it has to only use a simple random generator. I.e. rnd() function

Comment: I did try your method. But it only multiplied the decimal generated.

Comment: set @Rnd =  ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 10000 try this friend.

Comment: I think we have a winner. Thanks man! It works nicely.

Comment: I have updated in my answer also. Please accept it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @maxval TINYINT, @minval TINYINT
select @maxval=24,@minval=5

SELECT CAST(((@maxval + 1) - @minval) *
    RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) + @minval AS TINYINT)
```

Use this. set @maxval and @minval according to your need.

Or try this.

```
SELECT CAST(RAND() * 1000000 AS INT)
```

Or you can try this.

```
 Declare @Rnd INT;

   set @Rnd = CAST(RAND() * 1000000 AS INT)
    SELECT LEFT(Var1,2) & RIGHT(Var2,1) & @Rnd
    FROM MyTable;
```

or

```
Declare @Rnd INT;

     set @Rnd = ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 10000 
        SELECT LEFT(Var1,2) & RIGHT(Var2,1) & @Rnd
        FROM MyTable;
```